# UI Router "breadcrumbs" for a multi-step form AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, breadcrumbs

I'm creating a multi-step form in UI-Router on Angular 1, and I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

I'll use this example from scotch.io's UI-router multi-step form tutorial.

This is their index.html

```
<body ng-app="formApp">

    <div class="container">

        <!-- views will be injected here -->
        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Which pulls form.html and app.js

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/profile)
        .state('form.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'form-profile.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/interests
        .state('form.interests', {
            url: '/interests',
            templateUrl: 'form-interests.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/payment
        .state('form.payment', {
            url: '/payment',
            templateUrl: 'form-payment.html'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
})
```

form.html

```
  <div class="page-header text-center">
      <h2>Let's Be Friends</h2>

      <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
      <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
      <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
          <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
          <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
          <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
  <form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">
      <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
      <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
  </form>
```

From here there are 3 states of the form,

1. Profile
2. Interests
3. Payment

As soon as you get to step 1, you can see all of the links to *any of the steps* on the first page.

I'm looking to create a breadcrumb where you can only see Step 1 on page load, then Step 2 and Step 1, etc.

**However** - the catch is that since it's a multi-step form, I want the user to be able to go back to Step 1 after X steps *and still see* 1 through X in the breadcrumbs.

My current solution to demonstrate the end goal looks something like this

```
 <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
 <a ng-if="('form.payment' | isState) || ('form.interests' | isState) || (form | isState)" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
 <a ng-if="('form.payment' | isState) || (form | isState)" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
```

Not exactly elegant, but it works.

Basically if the user fills out 4 steps and goes back to 1, they should still see all 4 steps in the "breadcrumb" (the deepest level they've reached).

I'm thinking about storing which is the furthest state the user has achieved and rendering the number of links based on that, but not quite sure how to implement.

Comment: use `ui-router-extras`. The `StickyStates` and `DeepStatesRedirect` are capable of solving your problem. http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home

Comment: Thank you, Sticky States looks like exactly what I needed.